# Remove every repetition of substring with case sensitivity

Tags: c, string

I need to remove every repetition of substring from a string but with case sensitivity. When one substring is removed, the process goes again from the beginning of string.

Example:

```
char text[1000]="abcdef cde AbCDE";what[1000]="abc";cs;

OUTPUT for cs=1: "def cde AbCDE"
OUTPUT for cs=0: "def cde DE"
```

cs (case sensitive) 1 means care of case sensitivity, while cs 0 means don't care.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char *strremove(char *str, const char *sub) {
    char *p, *q, *r;
    if (*sub && (q = r = strstr(str, sub)) != NULL) {
        size_t len = strlen(sub);
        while ((r = strstr(p = r + len, sub)) != NULL) {
            while (p < r)
                *q++ = *p++;
        }
        while ((*q++ = *p++) != '\0')
            continue;
    }
    return str;
}
char* remove_all_substrings(char* str, const char* text, int cs) {
int i,e=0;
    if(cs==0){
        for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
        str[i]=tolower(str[i]);
    }
       while(1){
           e++;
           strremove(str, text);
           if(strstr(str,text)==NULL||e==100)break;
       }

  return str;
}
int main() {
   char text[1000] = "abcdef cde AbCDE";;
  char what[1000] = "abc";
  int cs = 1;
  printf("\"%s\"", remove_all_substrings(text, what, cs));
  return 0;
}
```

I get wrong output for cs=0, because in my approach I convert all characters from string to lowercase and then I remove them. Could you help me modify my code and give me some better approach for solving this task?

- Note: auxiliary strings are not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know why you are getting wrong output when `cs` value is `0`.

Note that functions `strcasecmp()` and `strncasecmp()` are conforming to
4.4BSD, POSIX.1-2001, whereas `strcasestr()` is a nonstandard extension. These function are not part of C standard. Using these may result in a non-portable code.

You have used `tolower()` in your code but you are modifying the original string. Instead of modifying the original string, simply compare the return value of `tolower()` when doing case insensitive comparison.

You can do:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* remove_all_substrings (char * str, const char * str_toremove, int cs) {
    if (str && str_toremove) {
        size_t len = strlen (str_toremove);
        int res = -1;
        char * ptr = str;
        size_t i = 0;

        while (str[i] && len) {
            if (cs) {
                if (str[i] == str_toremove[0]) {
                    res = 0;
                    size_t tmp_len = len;
                    while (--tmp_len) {
                        if (str[i + len - tmp_len] != str_toremove[len - tmp_len]) {
                            res = -1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (tolower (str[i]) == tolower (str_toremove[0])) {
                    res = 0;
                    size_t tmp_len = len;
                    while (--tmp_len) {
                        if (tolower (str[i + len - tmp_len]) != tolower (str_toremove[len - tmp_len])) {
                            res = -1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (res == 0) {
                i = i + len;
                res = -1;
            } else {
                *ptr++ = str[i++]; 
            }
        }

        if (len) {
            *ptr = '\0';
        }
    }

    return str;
}

void helper_func (char * str, const char * str_toremove, int cs) {
    printf("str : \"%s\", str_toremove : \"%s\", case sensitive : %d\n", 
        str ? str : "(NULL)", str_toremove ? str_toremove : "(NULL)", cs);

    char * res = remove_all_substrings(str, str_toremove, cs);

    printf("res : \"%s\"\n\n", res ? res : "(NULL)");
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf ("Invalid argument\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int cs = atoi (argv[1]);
    if ((cs != 0) && (cs != 1)) {
        printf ("Invalid commmand line argument value\n");
        return 0;
    }

    const char what[] = "abc";

    char text1[] = "abcdef cde AbCDE";;
    helper_func (text1, what, cs);

    char text2[] = "DuMMyabcd AbCDE";;
    helper_func (text2, what, cs);

    char text3[] = "idecbt HYTRg HGB jC";
    helper_func (text3, what, cs);

    char text4[] = "";
    helper_func (text4, what, cs);

    // test : pass NULL to input string pointer
    helper_func (NULL, what, cs);

    char text5[] = "abcDEFGHIABC";
    // test : pass NULL to toremove string pointer
    helper_func (text5, NULL, cs);

    helper_func (text5, "", cs);

    char text6[] = "abcABC";
    helper_func (text6, what, cs);

    char text7[] = "xxXXxx";
    helper_func (text7, "x", cs);

    char text8[] = "aBAcaDAe";
    helper_func (text8, "a", cs);

    return 0;
}
```

Usage : `./a.out <case_sensitive>`
Where value of `case_sensitive` is `0` or `1`. `0` means case insensitive removal and `1` means case sensitive removal.

Output - Case insensitive removal:

```
# ./a.out 0 
str : "abcdef cde AbCDE", str_toremove : "abc", case sensitive : 0
res : "def cde DE"

str : "DuMMyabcd AbCDE", str_toremove : "abc", case sensitive : 0
res : "DuMMyd DE"

str : "idecbt HYTRg HGB jC", str_toremove : "abc", case sensitive : 0
res : "idecbt HYTRg HGB jC"

str : "", str_toremove : "abc", case sensitive : 0
res : ""

str : "(NULL)", str_toremove : "abc", case sensitive : 0
res : "(NULL)"

str : "abcDEFGHIABC", str_toremove : "(NULL)", case sensitive : 0
res : "abcDEFGHIABC"

str : "abcDEFGHIABC", str_toremove : "", case sensitive : 0
res : "abcDEFGHIABC"

str : "abcABC", str_toremove : "abc", case sensitive : 0
res : ""

str : "xxXXxx", str_toremove : "x", case sensitive : 0
res : ""

str : "aBAcaDAe", str_toremove : "a", case sensitive : 0
res : "BcDe"
```

Output - Case sensitive removal:

```
# ./a.out 1
str : "abcdef cde AbCDE", str_toremove : "abc", case sensitive : 1
res : "def cde AbCDE"

str : "DuMMyabcd AbCDE", str_toremove : "abc", case sensitive : 1
res : "DuMMyd AbCDE"

str : "idecbt HYTRg HGB jC", str_toremove : "abc", case sensitive : 1
res : "idecbt HYTRg HGB jC"

str : "", str_toremove : "abc", case sensitive : 1
res : ""

str : "(NULL)", str_toremove : "abc", case sensitive : 1
res : "(NULL)"

str : "abcDEFGHIABC", str_toremove : "(NULL)", case sensitive : 1
res : "abcDEFGHIABC"

str : "abcDEFGHIABC", str_toremove : "", case sensitive : 1
res : "abcDEFGHIABC"

str : "abcABC", str_toremove : "abc", case sensitive : 1
res : "ABC"

str : "xxXXxx", str_toremove : "x", case sensitive : 1
res : "XX"

str : "aBAcaDAe", str_toremove : "a", case sensitive : 1
res : "BAcDAe"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written `strremove` to be case-sensitive (although "case-strict" might be a better term).

If you want to remove instances of a substring in a case-insensitive way, you cannot achieve that by modifying the *substring* and passing that to a case-sensitive function (unless you are willing to iterate over all possible case-permutations of the substring). You could make a copy of `str`, convert *that* to lower case, find the instances of `sub`, then use those locations to remove the substrings in the original `str`, but I suppose that might break the rule against auxiliary strings.

You must write a case-insensitive version of `strremove`. Which is not difficult; just use `strcasestr` instead of `strstr`.

But before you do that, you might change what `strremove` returns. As it stands, `strremove` accepts a pointer to the string, modifies the string, and then returns the pointer, which it never modified. The returned value is redundant, and in fact the calling code doesn't even retain it, so the function might just as well return `void`. I suggest it return a `bool` indicating whether it found (and removed) an instance of the substring; that way you could do without the awkward searching by `remove_all_substrings`.

Comment: thank you very much, could you give code as example